# How to get Camera Sensor Size in android device?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

can anyone know how to get sensor size of camera in android device ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

It is possible as of API level 21. From the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE):

> public static final Key SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE
>
> The physical dimensions of the full pixel array. [...]
>
> Units: Millimeters

I use this kind of code. Beware, there might be more than just one camera:

```java
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;

private SizeF getCameraResolution(int camNum)
{
    SizeF size = new SizeF(0,0);
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
        if (cameraIds.length > camNum) {
            CameraCharacteristics character = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[camNum]);
            size = character.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE);
        }
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        Log.e("YourLogString", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Note that Exception `CameraAccessException` needs to be caught.

Don't forget to add `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />` to your manifest.

Comment: Perfect solution, however, how to get the same value in versions prior to 21 API?

Comment: is this method is also write? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41032402/4548520

Comment: Seems it works wrong on some devices. I get incorrect angles of camera when using this sensor info size to calculate. Only for some devices I get the same results when using Camera2 API and Camera Legacy API

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to get width and height of the sensor of the camera with Camera1 Api too. Get horizontal and vertical angle of views and focal length and the rest is little trigonometry.

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
focalLength = params.getFocalLength();
horizontalViewAngle = params.getHorizontalViewAngle();
verticalViewAngle = params.getVerticalViewAngle();
```

A = Angle of view, l = focal length, h = sensor height/2 => tan(A/2) = h/l

For my device with focal length 1.15 mm and horizontal angle of view 54.8 degrees:

Sensor width = tan(54.8/2)*2*1.15 = 1.19mm

This value is same with what i get using method DomTomCat posted.