# Get angle of view of android camera device

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, angle

I want to know the angle of view from the camera, just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261776/determine-angle-of-view-of-smartphone-camera) question but using android.hardware.camera2. How can I reproduce the next code using the new camera2 library.

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
double thetaV = Math.toRadians(p.getVerticalViewAngle());
double thetaH = Math.toRadians(p.getHorizontalViewAngle());
```

Is there a way to do the same thing?

Comment: How to do it using `camera2` API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375781/without-additional-calculation-camera-or-camera2-apis-return-fov-angle-values-fo

Answer (score 9):

I search the google a person show possibility which he calculate FOV by Camera2 api

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54054/calculating-the-field-of-view-for-a-nexus-5

and found the equation

http://www.bobatkins.com/photography/technical/field_of_view.html

FOV (rectilinear) =  2 * arctan (frame size/(focal length * 2))

thus, we need to know **frame size** and **focal length**

the frame size is size of camera you can find the code on below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403558

also,  focal length you can find below link

[Manual focus in camera2, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170491/manual-focus-in-camera2-android)

and i combine the code like this

A function calculateFOV() calculate FOV angle

https://github.com/pchan1401-ICIL/Camera2FOV

Comment: Very nice write-up! I am currently blown-away that Camera 2 API makes it harder on the developer. I thought that successive API sets are meant to increase functionality.

Answer (score 5):

As far as my research has gone the answer is no. With the `camera2` API there is no call which can give you the vertical and horizontal viewing angle.

However, you don't need to use the `camera2` API to get those values. You can just use the original `camera` API to get the vertical and horizontal view angle and then use the `camera2` API for the rest of the app.

As far as I know the actual image capture firmware hasn't changed between the camera and `camera2` APIs.

Comment: very bad answer, it's possible to calculate, there is sensor size, focal length and other data available. `You can just use the original camera` == `Just use deprecated API` - so smart!...

Answer (score 4):

You could do it mathematically.

[image: Diagram]

You have:

- `L`, the width of an object
- `d`, the distance to the object

You want to calculate the angle `a` (alpha), the field of view.

Doing some trig:

```
tan(a/2) = (L/2)/d
tan(a/2) = L/2d
a/2 = atan(L/2d)
a = 2*atan(L/2d)
```

You can do that to calculate the horizontal field of view. Good luck!

Comment: I knew that solution, but it's not what I want because the users would need to do calibration and there are already to many steps before reaching that point and I don't want to overwhelm the users to do a more steps to be able to know the d and L

Comment: Oh yeah... Sorry I don't know a better solution :P

Answer (score 4):

Using `camera2` API we can do it like this:

```
val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics("0") // hardcoded first back camera id

val focalLength = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)?.firstOrNull() ?: return
val sensorSize = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE) ?: return
val horizontalAngle = (2f * atan((sensorSize.width / (focalLength * 2f)).toDouble())) * 180.0 / Math.PI
val verticalAngle = (2f * atan((sensorSize.height / (focalLength * 2f)).toDouble())) * 180.0 / Math.PI

// using camera2 API we got the same data as with legacy Camera API (with it was easier):
// val parameters = camera.getParameters()
// val horizontalAngle = parameters.getHorizontalViewAngle()
// val verticalAngle = parameters.getVerticalViewAngle()
```

But usually such values are for 4:3 aspect preview ratio, if you need it for 16:9 aspect ratio or other then check this [Without additional calculation Camera or camera2 APIs return FOV angle values for 4:3 aspect ratio by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375781/without-additional-calculation-camera-or-camera2-apis-return-fov-angle-values-fo)